# communication in iOS MVC implementation

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, delegates, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

In my **iOS** project with **MVC** implementation, I have implemented *communication between models and controllers through delegation.*
But some people say it should be done using **NSNotificationCentre** or **KVO**.

Is this right approach to notify controller through delegates when model changes?

When to use delegation, notification and **KVO** to notify controller when model changes?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, but in Cocoa (Touch) you should generally use KVO and NSNotificationCentre to implement observers.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 approaches are legitimate - which one you implement depends on your project design.

***Protocol/Delegate*** requires coupling (which can forfeit some *encapsulation*) that must be managed with weak/strong references.

***Notifications/observers*** must be added and removed and can quickly get out of control (e.g. duplicate notification names, retained observers, messages flying all over the place, etc.) The best approach with Notifications is to use individual (i.e. feature level) notification centers.

***KVO*** must also be added and removed, and there's no native way to check if any particular property is being observed or not, so you'll have to add that yourself. When an KVO/observed property goes nil your app will crash unless you remove the observer.